# A working command for solving a PolyLog equation? (Solve and NSolve don't work)

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, special-functions

I need to solve an equation of this form:

> NSolve[a + x^b + PolyLog[c, x] + PolyLog[d, 1/x] == 0, x]

Where $a, b, c, d$ are constants.

For the sake of simplicity we can make $a = b = c = d$.
Ok I know that with no chosen variables, the question is basically impossible but besides that, what I would like to get is a sort of plot in function of those constant, in a range let's say from $-3$ to $+5$ each one.

But then another problem would arise: having the plot, let's say for $a = b = c = d = 2$, how can I ask Mathematica to give me the numerical solution of the above equation? Solve seems not working!

(WM 10.0.2.0)

Comment: Try with `FindRoot`.

Comment: This is close. Since it is a transcendental equation you also need to restrict the range of the solution, so could do as follows. `In[433]:= NSolve[
 2 + x^2 + PolyLog[2, x] + PolyLog[2, 1/x] == 0 && -100 < x < 100, x]

Out[433]= {{x -> -0.370672770423}}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That excludes Complex solutions though

Comment: One can give different restrictions, viable elsewhere in C. Example: `In[438]:= NSolve[
 2 + x^2 + PolyLog[2, x] + PolyLog[2, 1/x] == 0 && -100 <= Re[x] <= 
   100 && 1 <= Im[x] <= 200, x]

Out[438]= {{x -> -0.1147574412 + 1.19969565036 I}}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That is a cool method! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to provide an answer slightly complementary to the comments. In fact, given equation has analytic solutions in special cases. We know that for negative integer orders `PolyLog` reduces to Bernoulli polynomials. Therefore we have *exact* roots for the orders $\ldots,-8,-6,-4,-2,-1$:

```
e = -4;
f = Simplify[
  a + x^b + PolyLog[c, x] + PolyLog[d, 1/x] /.{a -> e, b -> e, c -> e, d -> e}]
Solve[f == 0, x]
```

$x\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\x\to -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},\\x\to \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},\\x\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

```
e = -2;
f = Simplify[
  a + x^b + PolyLog[c, x] + PolyLog[d, 1/x] /. {a -> e, b -> e, c -> e, d -> e}]
Solve[f == 0, x]
```

$x\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\x\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

```
e = -1;
f = Simplify[
  a + x^b + PolyLog[c, x] + PolyLog[d, 1/x] /. {a -> e, b -> e, c -> e, d -> e}]
Solve[f == 0, x]
```

$x\to \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{71+3 \sqrt{105}}+\sqrt[3]{71-3 \sqrt{105}}+5\right),\\x\to -\frac{1}{6} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{71+3 \sqrt{105}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{71-3 \sqrt{105}}+\frac{5}{3},\\x\to -\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{71+3 \sqrt{105}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{71-3 \sqrt{105}}+\frac{5}{3}$